# C++ Boost: Get time with milliseconds

Tags: c++, date, boost, time

At the moment I am getting the date and time in the following way:

```
 std::string isoString = boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time());
 std::string date = isoString.substr(0,8);
 std::string time = isoString.substr(9,16);
```

Problem: The milliseconds are missing and I need this information. How can I obtain the time with milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock` :

```
 std::string isoString = boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
 std::string date = isoString.substr(0,8);
 std::string time = isoString.substr(9,20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [boost::posix_time::microsec_clock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_clock)

Answer (score 1):

Why not C++11?

```
long long timestamp()
{
    return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```